What's the real unlock condition for Endless Mode?
Both the Endless Mode unlock and the thing above it in the Unlocks list say that "Defeat the Master" is the condition for unlocking them, but I got Endless Mode only.
And I didn't defeat the fourth world, only got to Layer 15, so I'm quite sure I didn't "Defeat the Master", so what's the real condition for unlocking Endless Mode?

Weh. Sorry about that...
